# TabHost addFlags() not found

Tags: android, refresh, android-tabhost

I don't find the method addFlags, skd is 2.1

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
    .setIndicator("First Text")
    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    .setContent(new Intent(this, class1.class)));
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2")
    .setIndicator("Second Text")
    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    .setContent(new Intent(this, class2.class)));
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to run your app after you clean/build or are you getting an error? what's the error say?

Comment: I cannot even build after clean, the syntax error is addFlags(int) is undefined for the type TabHost.TabSpec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Intent` class has `addFlags` method. Think your code should be like the following:

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2")
    .setIndicator("Second Text")
    .setContent(
      new Intent(this, class2.class)
          .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
    ));
```

Comment: It doesn't compile with this :/

Comment: 03-01 17:22:26.179: E/AndroidRuntime(808): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tasklite.android/activity.TabLayoutActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tasklite.android/activity.TabLayoutActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tasklite.android/activity.TabLayoutActivity}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@44cb8658 is not valid; is your activity running?

Comment: So, it's not a compilation problem. It's hard to add somehing. You should provide more code from your TabActivity